# Create a blank csv file within VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv, vbscript

Run into a little problem. I am running 10's of macros from VBScript, in different spreadsheets. Which works great, but have come across a simple problem. One of the macros I need export a few values into a new CSV/txt file in the current directory.

When I try the `FileSystemObject` from within VBA, it fails. (I presume because I am already running the macro from VBScript). So I searched for how to create a CSV or txt file. And every answer says  `SaveAs`. Which is not what I need. I need to create a brand new CSV/txt file and populate it later on. But I couldn't find a Create_CVS_File option, which was NOT `SaveAs`.

My code (see below) is failing at: `Set csvFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("unknown_models.csv")`.

```
Dim ClientCodeSelection As Range
Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
file = Dir(Path)
csv_exist = 0

For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(numRows - 1, numColumns), Range(Columns(Rng1.Column), Columns(Rng1.Column)))
    'first check for correct event type, i.e not 'none franchised.'
    If Not LCase(c.Value) Like LCase("*non *") Then
        If InStr(sn1_joined, LCase(Cells(c.Row, rng2.Column))) > 0 Then
            'all good, not missing move on.
        Else
            'record value into csv or text file, called unknown_model.csv
            'first check to see if the file exists in the current directory
            While (file <> "")
                If InStr(file, "unknown_models.csv") Then
                   csv_exist = 1
                Else
                End If
                file = Dir
            Wend

            'if file didnt exist create it, otherwise add the data
            If csv_exist = 1 Then
                'just add data
            Else
                'create
                Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set csvFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("unknown_models.csv", True)
                'now add data
            End If

            Total = Total + 1
        End If
    End If
Next c
If Not ClientCodeSelection Is Nothing Then ClientCodeSelection.Select
```

Got it working with Vincent's fantastic help. Final code:

```
Dim ClientCodeSelection As Range
Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
ForAppending = 8

For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(numRows - 1, numColumns), Range(Columns(Rng1.Column), Columns(Rng1.Column)))
    'first check for correct event type, i.e not 'none franchised.'
    If Not LCase(c.Value) Like LCase("*non *") Then
        If InStr(sn1_joined, LCase(Cells(c.Row, rng2.Column))) > 0 Then
            'all good, not missing move on.
        Else
            'record value into csv or text file, called unknown_model.csv
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set openFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Path & "unknown_models.txt", ForAppending, True)
            openFile.Write Cells(c.Row, rng2.Column) & ","
            openFile.Close
            Total = Total + 1
        End If
    End If
Next c

If Not ClientCodeSelection Is Nothing Then ClientCodeSelection.Select
```

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong about FSO. Post your code.

Comment: Done...thanks for looking.

Comment: There is a problem with your `While... Wend` loop. If the first file returned by `Dir` is not 'unknow_models.csv', but there is already an existing 'unknown_models.csv', your code will try to create one.

Comment: I just changed the code. While now just checks if it exists, if not create.

Comment: Given that you already are using a FSO object, why don't use the method FileExist to check for the file?

Comment: The check works fine, i have tested, if its already there then it just carries on. It fails when it tries to create new one.

Comment: You are not providing the full path for creating the file, you are probably trying to create it somewhere you don't have write permission. Try `Set csvFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Path & "unknown_models.csv", True)`

Comment: Note that the simplest way to write a csv file is probably to use the statements [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx)  to open and/or create the file (no need to check for existence), [Write #](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264524.aspx) to write data and [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264418.aspx) to close the file after writing.

Comment: Vincent, ty. That helped, it created the file in the correct Dir, then came up with the error 'Permission Denied'. I cancelled the error and the vbs carried on quite happy. And the file it created is still there. Just got that permission error. Anyway i can force permissions? As i cannot change the location, which will change each week.

Comment: FYI, i tried with just opentextfile, and it fails if the file doesnt exist. Says invalid procedure.

Comment: With your help, I am nearly there. Changed it to txt file and now no permission issues. Also works well without the whiles and just have 'Open', now having an issue with writing to a new line for each one and the correct value. But getting there! :-) thankyou!

Comment: How do i add to your rep, Vincent?

Comment: If your final code is working, you should post it as an answer and accept it (you are allowed to do so).

Comment: For several reasons, I'd suggest to open and close the file outside of the loop. ;)